# The complexity of H(x) in the Ladner's Theorem

Tags: complexity-theory

I was self-learning the complexity theory using the [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach by Arora and Barak](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/). When studying the Ladner's Theorem, the textbook mentioned a function $H(x)$ as shown below, and claim that the complexity of $H(x)$ is $O(n^3)$. But I don't understand how to proof this claim.

In the book wrote:

---

For every function $H\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, define $SAT_H=\{\psi01^{n^{H(n)}}: \psi \in SAT \ and \ n=|\psi|\}$.

$H$ is defined as follows:

$H(n)$ is the smallest number $i<\log \log n$ such that for every $x\in\{0,1\}^*$ with $|x|\le \log n$, $M_i$ outputs $SAT_H (x)$ within $i|x|^i$ steps. If there is no such number $i$ then $H(n)=\log \log n$.

---

[The draft version of the book](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf) provides a simple explanation of the complexity, but I failed to understand the proof. In particular, what is step (3) and how combining three steps makes the conclusion. The draft wrote:

---

There is a trivial algorithm to compute H(n) in $O(n^3)$ time. After all, we only need to (1) compute $H(k)$ for every $k \leq \log n$, (2) simulate at most $\log \log n$ machines for every input of length at most $\log n$ for $\log \log n (\log n)^{\log \log n} = o(n)$ steps, and (3) compute SAT on all the inputs of length at most $\log n$.

---

(Note that the definition of $H(x)$ in the draft is slightly different from the textbook, but I think they are equivalent.)

My current proof is wrong, and I'm trying to find where I got it wrong.

1. We have $\log \log n$ TM to check.
2. Each TM runs on $\Sigma^{\log n}_{i=0} 2^i = O(n)$ inputs, since this is the maximum amount of possible $x$.
3. Since we simulate $M_i$ on $x$ in $i|x|^i$ steps, where $|x| < \log n$, a run takes $\log \log n (\log n)^{\log \log n}$, which is $O(n)$.
4. The rest of the steps are constant time.

Therefore, the overall time complexity $O((\log \log n) \times n \times n)$, which is $O((\log \log n) n^2)$. This is probably wrong.

Comment: I don't think that $O(n^3)$ was meant as an exact bound. The only important thing is that $H$ can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: Oh, I never think that the bound is not tight. Thanks for the hint. Just wondering, is $O((\log \log n) n^2)$ tight upper bound?

Comment: I haven’t checked your calculations. The details are not that important.